# Setting DB2SECURITYLABEL upon insert using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I have a requirement to set the DB2SECURITYLABEL of a row upon inserting that row into the database via Hibernate. I've been unsuccessful thus far and I'm seeking advice on how to set the DB2SECURITYLABEL in Java and have Hibernate do the insert for me.

Inside of my entity, I have defined the following:

```
@Column(name="slabel")  //this matches the name of the DB2SECURITYLABEL column
private byte[] slabel;

public void setSlabel(byte[] slabel){
     this.slabel = slabel;
}

public byte[] getSlabel(){
     return this.slabel;
}
```

In my controller I convert the hex string that represents my security label into a byte[], setSlabel with that byte[], and save the record through a Spring Data Repository .save(entity). Upon saving that record, the db2 driver throws an error:

> SQLCODE=-20402 SQLSTATE=42519 .

This error code is indicative of a record being saved without a required DB2SECURITYLABEL.

Assumptions:

- I am able to insert/select into/from this table via commandline using the same
  security label. insert into schema.table (field1, slabel) values
  (123,x'FFF01010101000CABBBBFFF')  <-not my real label. I can select the records that I insert via commandline and in my application.
- I am able to retrieve existing records with DB2SECURITYLABELS
  and read the label as a byte[] and as hex string using my application.
- I believe I am inserting a correct label. I have verified the byte[]
  that I am applying to the object is correct. I was able to insert a
  record with a valid DB2SECURITYLABEL via the commandline, and
  retrieved it in my application; the two byte[] for the
  DB2SECURITYLABELs are identical and convert back to the same hex
  string.

Has anyone set a DB2SECURITYLABEL in a Java object as a byte[] and used Hibernate to save the data to a db2 database?

I appreciate any assistance.